# Is there a DuPont housing, but with larger body and index key like an IDC connector?

Tags: connector

We have a project in which we want to connect individual wires to an existing PCB that has two 2x5 pin IDC connectors.

Here is the board with the two IDC connectors:

[image: Our PCB with two 2x5 IDC sockets]

All the IDC connectors that I have found that mate with this connector seem to all use a ribbon cable since that's what IDC really means (the piercing mechanism.)

[image: 2x5 IDC connector with ribbon cable]

We want to use individual 28 AWG wires instead of a ribbon cable.

Is there such a thing as a connector that is just like the IDC connector housing, but instead of accepting a ribbon cable, it accepts wires with crimped-on DuPont pins or DuPont sockets, just like a standard 2x5 DuPont housing?

[image: DuPont connector housing with individual wires with crimped sockets]

A 2x5 DuPont housing will physically fit onto the IDC connectors on this board, but there is a lot of space around the connector and there is no indexing key which makes it possible to plug the connector in the wrong way around.

[image: DuPont connector is too small and does not have a key indexing tab]

Comment: Like one of [these](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/wire-housings-plugs/3606229)?

Comment: Honestly, if I wanted it that badly I would desolder those headers and replace them with latching polarized headers with matching crimp housings.

Comment: Those *are* IDC connectors, but the term IDC doesn't refer to the type of connector itself, but how it's attached to the wire. (it stands for "insulation-displacement connector".) The type of connector I would just call a .1" header.

Comment: I do not know if dupont makes what you want. But there are compatible housings that accept individually crimped wires that will probably work reliably. "IDC" means insulation displacement contact. Technically, those headers are not IDC. They are through-hole solder mount. Of course, most of the plugs that mate with those headers ARE IDC types designed to be used with ribbon cable, as you say. But those headers are still not actually IDC. There is such a thing as an IDC header that solders to the PCB. Wires can be pressed directly into the header with no housing or plug.

Comment: @user57037 dupont doesn't, and as far as I can tell never has, made connectors anything like this. I have no idea how they ended up with the "dupont" name attached to them.

Answer (score 0):

Some call those "bump" connectors. ("IDC" applies to all sorts of connectors, not just the type in your pictures, so it can be confusing. The term "Bump" is specific for this kind of connector.)

Yes, plugs for "bump" connector for discrete wires do exist, though they are not common. I am assuming the pitch of that connector in 2.54 mm. I found that Hirose makes the HIF3BA series. [Hirose webpage](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/HIF3FC), [pdf spec sheet](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=HIF3FC&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D49683_en), [Digikey page](https://www.digikey.se/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/HIF3BA-10D-2-54C-63/26-HIF3BA-10D-2-54C-63-ND/12758591). Unfortunately, I can't find any stock of them.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/102387-1/289274

Comment: Thanks: that one is in stock. However, I believe that it doesn't completely fill the PCB header, the way a "bump" plug would. Which is a complaint that @MakerspaceJim had.

Comment: The one you suggested is only 0.5" wide. The one I suggested is wider (0.68"). I am not saying mine will fit correctly. But if mine leaves a gap yours will leave a wider gap. The other dimension (vertical height) mine is a bit smaller than yours (0.227 vs 0.244). Maybe that is what you are referring to. But I thought the OP was more concerned with the horizontal gap.

Answer (score 0):

No probably not as an off the shelf part. You typically don't get adapters in two standards like that. The term for the header is a shrouded header.

For one off project you can 3d print your own hybrid connector or print a shell that you glue to a regular dupont connector.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Molex C-Grid III](https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/part-detail/901420010).

Compare to a typical shrouded IDC/ribbon header: [3M 2500 Series Drawing](https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/330367O/3m-four-wall-header-2500-series-ts-0770.pdf)

The 10-pin plug is 6.2 x 12.9 mm max, which fits within a rectangular opening 6.35 x 13.2 mm (nominal), say in the 90130 series header.  (Curiously, they give a generous min tolerance which would interfere with the plug, but I wonder if that's because they sometimes make it with a closer fit around the 'H' shape, the extra nubs on the corners.)  The locking/friction ramp fits in a 3.85 mm wide notch, and the intended pin length is 6.75 mm.

The IDC header has a 6.35 x 18.0 mm opening, 4.2 mm wide notch, and 6.2 mm long pins.

The ramp/tab is also 1 mm tall, more than enough to interfere with the shroud in wrong positions.  (The D and E notch options, seen in longer connectors, look off-grid enough that the plug probably doesn't fit off-center and backwards in those connectors either.)

The plug will not fill the width of the header, so will probably sit a bit loose (easy to rock back and forth, risk of bending pins), but it should be retained well enough by socket or housing friction, and it doesn't look like any filing would be necessary.

C-Grid terminals of course are not Dupont style, and will need an appropriate  crimp tool and such to use.  (I suspect Dupont style *exactly* is impossible, as, how could there be a pin retention tab molded into the connector, *and* the polarization key sticking out?  So I'm assuming any 0.025" square pin compatible socket is all that's desired.)